# Can't get jQueryUI's sortable dropOnEmpty to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an application where competitors are squadded for an event. The UI for moving competitors between squads uses jQuery-UI's accordion and sortable widgets. The accordion is initially collapsed, and each header shows the squad number and the number of competitors in the squad. To move a competitor, the squad the competitor is in is expanded, as is the destination squad. The competitor is then dragged from one list to the other, and the counts in the headers for each side is updated. The list is automatically resorted when the competitor is dropped into it.  Competitors can also be dragged from either side to the other.

All this works great until all the competitors are dragged out of a squad, leaving it empty. After that, I can no longer drop a competitor into the empty squad, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

I've created a JSFiddle that demonstrates the UI in action, at http://jsfiddle.net/jcwren/5V5HU/. Open squad 2 on the left, squad 1 on the right, and drag Scooby, Shaggy and Thelma to squad 1. Now try to drag one of them back into squad 1.

As an added bonus, I'd like to be able to drag a competitor into an UN-expanded list, by dropping it on the header. I confess to having not having spent much time trying to get that to work, as the empty list problem has been frustrating me.

Code to make StackOverflow happy (although it's pretty useless without the accompanying HTML...)

```
$('.ulLeft, .ulRight').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    active: 'none'
});

//
//  Gets called once by the source ('remove') side, and once by the destination
//  ('receive') side. First we resort the ordered list items (which isn't really
//  necessary for the remove side, but we'll fix that later), then we replace the
//  HTML content of this side with the sorted contents (this side is expanded, we
//  see all the elements in it), and then we update the list on the opposite (which
//  will only be visible if we're moving to the same squad). We need to do this so
//  if that squad is expanded later, it will have the same list content.
//
function updateList(thisOL, oppositeOL) {
    var squadNumber = thisOL.attr('squadnumber');
    var olNew = _.sortBy(thisOL.find('li'), function (li) {
        return $(li).text();
    });

    thisOL.html(olNew);
    $('.' + oppositeOL + '_' + squadNumber).html($(olNew).clone());

    _.each(['ulLeft', 'ulRight'], function (side) {
        var ht = $('#h4_' + side + '_squad_' + squadNumber);
        var sn = ht.html().replace(/\(\d+\)/, '(' + olNew.length + ')');
        ht.html(sn);
    });
}

//
//  Create sortables, connect left list to right, right list to left
//
$('.olLeft').sortable({
    connectWith: '.olRight',
    cursor: 'move',
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        updateList($(this), 'olRight');
    },
    remove: function (event, ui) {
        updateList($(this), 'olRight');
    }
});

$('.olRight').sortable({
    connectWith: '.olLeft',
    cursor: 'move',
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        updateList($(this), 'olLeft');
    },
    remove: function (event, ui) {
        updateList($(this), 'olLeft');
    }
});

$('.ulLeft, .ulRight, .olLeft, .olRight').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the issue is that your list's height is 0. Putting something like the following in the `updateList` function fixes that issue.

```
if (thisOL.children().length == 0) {
    thisOL.height(10);
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5V5HU/14/

Comment: For the bonus question - you would need to set the header to be a droppable object when it's collapsed. Not sure how much work that would be, but I think it should be feasible.

Comment: That makes sense. While the padding is still there because of the 'ol' element, there are no items, so there's no height. To make that completely work, I had to add an else clause to remove the style attribute. (Can't figure out how to make code post in the reply, the backtick doesn't seem to do anything)